# Tunneling a random port ( 9700 ) through an HTTPS proxy

Tags: ssh, https, http-proxy

I would like to find a way to access port 9700, but my proxy only allows port 8080 and 443. Is there a way to tunnel through port 443 to access port 9700?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are behind a proxy that is only allowing outgoing traffic on TCP port 8080 and 443, then the only way you can get traffic to other ports is to have something outside of the firewall listening on TCP port 443 or 8080 and willing to forward traffic for you to your desired destination host at port 9700.

If you have a home Internet connection with enough speed you might be able to run such software on your home computer.  This would require:

- you to remember your home's IP address OR sign up with a service such as dyndns.org or no-ip.com that allows you to run an update client that keeps a domain name up-to-date with your IP
- you to configure your home router or internet gateway to forward incoming traffic on TCP ports 443 or 8080 to a computer in your home.  If you use dyndns.org or no-ip.com, you should install the "dynamic update client" on this machine.
- you to install and configure software that does the forwarding for you.  Since you are only doing this for a single port you might try something simple like [TrivialProxy](http://www.xrayapp.com/trivialproxy/).

Since this proxy has TCP port 443 open, you also might consider signing up for an SSL VPN service which will operate on port 443 and look like HTTPS SSL traffic.  I've never used any third-party SSL VPN services so I don't know of any to mention off hand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've got a static ip at home and I've opened port 22 . I would have to open port 443 as well and then tunnel the home connection to 9700 is that right ? In terms of security would it be a bad thing to open 443 ?

Comment: if that is the case, how would you tunnel twice ? once at home through 443 and then tell my home connection to tunnel to 9700 ?

Comment: "Tunneling" means something different than the way it seems you mean it.  This situation is just straight-up forwarding; you'd have to run a program on your home PC that is receiving traffic from TCP port 443 and then does nothing but resend that traffic to the machine you want, TCP port 9700.  There is a risk in that if you use something like TrivialProxy that doesn't use authentication, anyone who hits your IP address will have their traffic redirected as well.  If you need something that is for more than temporary use then I'd look into SSL VPNs which will do authentication and tunneling.